# Misconfigured Certificate for Apple Developer Downloads?

Tags: security, xcode, developer-program

Since this morning, I've been trying to download the new Xcode 9 beta 3 from the Apple Developer portal.

When I click the "Download" button, I am seeing a security warning saying the site identity could not be verified due to non matching host name in the certificate (the exact phrase is different across browsers).

Viewing the certificate details shows that the CN is "a248.e.akamai.net".

It looks like a misconfiguration in Apple's server.

Is anyone else seeing this on Apple Developer portal today?

Can I trust the download anyway (since I was redirected from a trusted page, and since Xcode is verified again when installed on the mac)?

[image: Safari Screenshot]

Comment: Not really sure what is going on for you. Just commenting to say I just tried the download myself (on Chrome/Win) and the download started okay. Checked the certificate and it doesn't mention akamai at all. Apple did use Akamai's CDN but I thought they'd moved to using their own now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying that on different machines, networks and browsers. They all failed...

Comment: This might be a region specific problem. Which country are you in?

Comment: You could also try tweeting https://twitter.com/AppleSupport just in case it is a configuration problem on their end.